# Core Data - Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, ios7, nsoperation

I'm getting a lot of crash reports with the following error. So far it is happening only on devices running iOS7.

```
Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

Here's the general code of a JSON Parsing Operation. The line causing the error is noted.

```
- (void)main {

    @autoreleasepool {

        self.objectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
                                       initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        self.objectContext.parentContext = [[CoreDataController sharedController] managedObjectContext];
        [self.objectContext setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES];
        [self.objectContext performBlock:^{
            id jsonObject = [self.rawData objectFromJSONData];

            @try {
                [self parseJsonObject:jsonObject];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Caught Exception: %@", exception);
            }

            [self parsingFinished];

        }];

    }
}

- (void)parsingFinished {

    if ([self.parsingResults count] ==0){

        [self parsingFailed:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"Parsing or Loading Error"
                                                code:100
                                            userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Parsing finished with no data."
                                                                                 forKey:@"error"]]];
        return;
    }


    @try {
        NSError *saveError = nil;
        if (![self.objectContext save:&saveError])
            NSLog(@"saveError %@", saveError);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Caught Exception: %@", exception);
    }



    [[CoreDataController sharedController] saveContext]; //ERROR

    if (self.parsingCompletionBlock)
        self.parsingCompletionBlock(self.parsingResults);
}
```

The Core Data Controller method is here:

```
- (void)saveContext {

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        [managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            //THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
            if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }


}
```

I think it has something to do with multithreaded Core Data, but I'm lost. Is there a fix visible in the code above?

EDIT: Here's more of the crash log.

```
Fatal Exception NSInternalInconsistencyException
This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.

com.apple.main-thread Crashed
0 ...    libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8
1    libsystem_pthread.dylib     pthread_kill + 58
2    libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 76
3    libc++abi.dylib     abort_message + 74
4    libc++abi.dylib     default_terminate_handler() + 252
5    libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_terminate() + 192
6    libc++abi.dylib     std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
7    libc++abi.dylib     __cxa_increment_exception_refcount
8    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_rethrow + 42
9    CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1494
10   My App     
CoreDataController.m line 64
__33-[CoreDataController saveContext]_block_invoke
11   CoreData    developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 88
12 ...   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 66
13   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 22
14   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 268
15   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
16   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1300
17   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
18   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
19   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 138
20   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

Comment: did you try NSObject class instead like this?

Comment: While building your models, are there any required properties that do not get populated?

Comment: @MikeD I just went through all my model objects. All Properties and Relationships are marked as Optional.

Comment: More information about the error would be useful.

Comment: @Mundi I added more information about the crash log.

Comment: @soleil I am facing same issue with core data. Have you found any solution on this issue?